# UICollectionView not loading new cells when scrolling horizontally

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am placing a **horizontal scroll** `UICollectionViewController` inside of another `UICollectionViewController` cell. I am doing this because I want to create an image slider like effect.

Code for horizontal scroll UICollectionViewController:

```
class BusinessPhotosViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    var photos = [String]()
    let cellId = "photos"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        }

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .red
        collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = true

        collectionView?.register(BusinessPhotoCells.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! BusinessPhotoCells

        if photos.count != 0 {
            let imageUrl = photos[indexPath.item]
            let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
            cell.logoImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.height-10, height: view.frame.height-10)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

In another class I add this horizontal scroll UICollectionViewController as such:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //ADDING SCROLL CELL HERE
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let scrollCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: pictureCellId, for: indexPath)

            scrollCell.backgroundColor = .blue

            let bizVC = BusinessPhotosViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

            scrollCell.addSubview(bizVC.view)

            bizVC.view.anchor(top: scrollCell.topAnchor, left: scrollCell.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollCell.bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: scrollCell.frame.width, height: scrollCell.frame.height)

            return scrollCell
        }

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: listCellId, for: indexPath) as! CouponCell


        return cell
    }
```

**Edit: Adding numberOfItemsInSection per comments**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 0
        }
        if section == 1 {
            return 1
        }

        return coupons.count
    }
```

I return 1 for this section because I only want 1 horizontal scroll cell...Below that horizontal scroll cell (in section 2) I then have a list of vertical scroll cells that work as expected.

This results in something like this where only 3 squares are loaded up not the 10 as expected:

[image]

**EDIT: ADDING IMAGE OF WHAT MY VIEW LOOKS LIKE NOW**
[image]

Comment: in the second viewController, what do you return into numberOfItemsInSection ?
More, in the first viewController, don't return 10, just return photos.count, so you don't have to check if photos.count > 0

Comment: @AndreaAbbate Yeah I know I just returned 10 right now because I wanted to see the issue more clearly (and I haven't generated date to the photos array yet). I have edited included the numberofItemsInSection so that you can see what that looks like.

Comment: Actually, I can't understand why are you avoiding to use section 0 and why do you use more sections, neither what's a scrollCell and a CouponCell. As I understood before: your first collectionView has differents rows/sections, each row is a set of images (es. businessPhoto) and you can scroll vertically and horizontally. If it's so, I think this is not a good solution. If I didn't understand well, please explain or show an example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @AndreaAbbate The first section (section == 0) is a section I am using for a custom header, so I don't need any sections returned for it. The second section (section ==1) is where I want the section with the horizontal scroll. The third ection (section == 2) is where I have a vertical scroll with a custom cell I created (couponCell). Please see the edited image that will clarify this all for you. So section == 1 is where I am trying to just create 1 horizontal scroll collectionview controller. The rest of the layout is setup fine. Does this better clarify?

Comment: @AndreaAbbate so as per the code I have here... The BusinessPhotosViewController is the class I am using for the horizontal scroll section (section ==1). The other sections are handled by other classes and work fine, but the code I have here shows how I am instantiating that class for the horizontal view and what the class looks like right now.

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear, i'll try to reproduce this asap. However, I think it's good to use different collectionView instead of nested ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180947/discussion-between-mufc-and-andrea-abbate).